# Simple Versioning of a Gradle Project

Tags: java, gradle, versioning, gitlab-ci

I have a simple Java project that creates a JAR using gradle.  The project is centrally managed in a gitlab repo and built with Gitlab CI.  I'm okay if every commit in a certain branch is considered "released" (ie not SNAPSHOT).

Most plugins try to do a lot and add a lot of complexity and confusion.  I just need something really simple and clean.  I'm okay with just using gradle.properties to manage the major and minor versions and Gitlab's CI_PIPELINE_IID as the "patch".  I'm also ok with something easier than this, if possible.

Does anyone have a sample project that can easily manage versions?

Comment: your jar file is a library or a runnable jar file?

Comment: It is runnable and "shaded".

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to put it all together...

gradle.properties:

```
majorVersion=1
minorVersion=2
```

build.gradle

```
..
version "${majorVersion}.${minorVersion}.${System.env.CI_PIPELINE_IID?:'dev'}"
..
```

I'm using Spring Boot, so I can just do a `gradle bootJar` and a properly versioned JAR shows up in `build/libs`.  If the build was outside of Gitlab CI, the JAR ends in `dev` instead of the `CI_PIPELINE_IID` value.  Of course, CI_PIPELINE_IID can be set to anything on the dev machine.